# Probrema Codeigniter intelephense 1009 e 1035

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, codeigniter-3, multiple-file-upload

Estou tendo um problemas com a class CI_controller. o Problema esta relatado em fotos a seguir, porem ele se resume em nao encontrar biblioteca CI_controler [intelephense 1009], consequentemente nao conseguindo usar suas funções [intelephense 1035] , ja busquei em diversos sites, por soluções para ele, algumas soluções até disfarçam, mas não resolvem o problema, e a minha grande duvida, vem de que, o código em si, está todo copiado da documentação do codeigniter, para fazer upload de fotos. Ficatei Grato se alguem puder me dar uma força com isso[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá e boas-vindas ao site. É importante **[edit]** e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema (NÃO delete e NÃO repita a pergunta)** ([e não usar imagens para mostrar códigos e logs como imagens](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635)), com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva e então aguarde o processo de reabertura (que será avaliado por outros usuários). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.